# Copy database error (DNN): No primary or candidate keys in the referenced table that match the referencing column list in the foreign key

Tags: sql-server-2005, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

> DNN version: 5.6.2
>
> Tool: SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Action: Copy database
>
> Error: There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'Roles' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key
>   'FK_UserRoles_Roles'

I tried searching for this error online, but all searches lead to topics where this error is encountered while creating a foreign key to a non-unique column. In my case, the key is already created. I double-checked that the RoleId column is the primary key on the Roles table and it is indeed the column the foreign key 'FK_UserRoles_Roles' references.

Any help to fix this is appreciated. Alternatively, what will be a quick way to copy the structure and data of my database apart from the "Copy Database" option?

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend doing a backup and restoring to a new database.

Comment: Thanks @notandy, I tried that and got it to work after a few modifications - since I was restoring to the same server, I had to change some options and specify different log names, etc.
I would still like to understand the cause of the original issue though.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an aspnet_Roles table in the DotNetNuke database.  This is part of the ASP.NET authentication provider.  Your problem may be not migrating the data in both the aspnet_ tables as well as the DNN tables.